# How to refer to /data files in R package

Tags: r, package, cran

I have submitted a R package to CRAN. I need to include example .csv files which I included under the /data directory.

To get the R CMD check to pass, I have to have the examples in the .Rd file to refer to data .csv files as below

```
 pkg-function(system.file("data", <csv file>, package = pkg-name),par1) -- (1)
```

Using this format passes the R CMD check and also works after the package is installed rather than actual path names.

But I want the user to be able refer to the .csv files in a simple way as follows

```
pkg-function(path-to-file, par1) -- (2)
```

Since the examples in the .Rd file will be in form (1) it will confuse the user.

Is there a clean way to call the package functions in the examples (.Rd) as format (2)

Comment: `pkg-function` is not a valid object name in R.

Comment: That was just a generalized way of referring to the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a change in expectations in your case. Instead of trying to find a way to make a clear and obvious example in as little code as possible, perhaps you can write a little more code with comments to illustrate what you are doing.

For example:

```
#* retrieve the file path of a data file installed with
#* [your package's name] 
#* see '?system.file' for details.
Path <- system.file (...)

#* execute function
pkg-function (Path, par1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that sounds reasonable.